# Overwrite method in compiled library at run time

Tags: java

I'm looking to overwrite a method in the `com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCrypt`class at run time to aid in reverse engineering a piece of malware, the malware uses a custom AES implementation that I am trying to replicate in the `expandToSubKey` method. How would I go about overwriting the method at run time so that I could setup a standard AES decrypt method to use my modified function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible. There seem to be two approaches.

1. **ClassTransformer Approach:** Transform the byte code for the `com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCrypt` class when you start the java process using java assist. There is a very good blog outlining everything you need to do [here](https://blog.newrelic.com/engineering/diving-bytecode-manipulation-creating-audit-log-asm-javassist/).
2. **Boot Classpath Approach:** This is probably the easiest way to go. Java has a mechanism that allows you to patch core java classes for your application, this mechanism is the boot classpath and is described in this [book](http://media.techtarget.com/tss/static/articles/content/CovertJava/Sams-CovertJava-15.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

You can create class with exactly same full name in your project, copy code from library's class into your new class and change pieces of code you want to change. When JVM classloader will be asked to load `AESCrypt` class it will first look for it in classes inside your project so your custom version of `AESCrypt` will be loaded.

Answer (score 2):

The class is final. It can't be in standard way override the class.

```
 final class AESCrypt extends SymmetricCipher implements AESConstants
```

Depending on how you want to implement changes, you can do this with:

- Creating a new class and **implements AESConstants and  extends SymmetricCipher**. Just how you like it
- Use **reflection** to have access to private methods to change the behavior to that you expect (not recommended)